# Espresso android - IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient already registered

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, android-espresso-recorder

Getting IllegalStateException exception randomly running on AWS, for the below defined Rule

```
@Rule
public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(<permissions>)
```

Here is the exception trace

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub$Proxy@8129d6balready registered!
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2079)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.connect(IUiAutomationConnection.java:427)
at android.app.UiAutomation.connect(UiAutomation.java:241)
at android.app.Instrumentation.getUiAutomation(Instrumentation.java:2167)
at android.app.Instrumentation.getUiAutomation(Instrumentation.java:2124)
at androidx.test.runner.permission.UiAutomationShellCommand.<init>(UiAutomationShellCommand.java:65)
at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.addPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:92)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule.grantPermissions(GrantPermissionRule.java:100)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule.grant(GrantPermissionRule.java:94)
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: @lukjar not yet, actually for me it happens very rare say once in a week. Probably I will look at it later.

Comment: @lukjar FYI, have filed a bug here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189885575. In case you have figured this out please help me.

Comment: It seems the issue is reproducible on AWS Test Farm only

Comment: @Duna Probably you are correct, I have switched my tests to tun on local machine dedicated for tests only and seems this issue haven't encountered so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Android emulator Bug!  Try another or delete and create new again...

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val lGrantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

Comment: The emulator in on AWS test Farm...

Answer (score 0):

This may be your emulator issue. Try any one of below solutions,

- Try cold booting your emulator(restarting)
- Or wipe emulator data
- Or create new emulator and try again